# Pull multiple fields from an object in get;set;

Tags: apex, getter

I have the following code linked to a vf page for a basic custom related list.  I've figured out that it is not working due to not pulling the `mr.Sample_ID__c`because the `get;set;` at the top only pulls the `mr.Id`.

So my question is how do I pull multiple fields in as part of this top method?  I couldn't seem to find an example in documentation.

```
public class MatchExtension
{
// Get,Set current match record info
public Match_Record__c mr {get;set;}
//Assuming I'd pull other fields here?
// find related match records on the sample
public List <Match_Record__c> matchList
{
    get
    {
        if (matchList == null)
        {
            matchList = [SELECT Enrollment_Status__c,
                                Enrollment_Sub_Status__c,
                                Sub_Status_Reason__c,
                                CreatedDate,
                                Name,
                                Match_ID__c,
                                Sample_ID__c
                          FROM  Match_Record__c
                         WHERE  Sample_ID__c = :mr.Sample_ID__c]; //How do I pull this into query with top lines?
        }
        return matchList;
    }
    private set;
}
// set standard controller for the object
public MatchExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.mr = (Match_Record__c)stdController.getRecord();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use one of three following methods:

## Include the Field in Your Page

If you put the following code in your page, it'll pull the field:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="false" value="{!Match_Record__c.Sample_ID__c}" />
```

## Add the Field to the Query

You can add additional fields using addFields:

```
public MatchExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        stdController.addFields(new String[] { 'Sample_ID__c' });
    }
    this.mr = (Match_Record__c)stdController.getRecord();
}
```

## Query Manually

```
public MatchExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.mr = (Match_Record__c)stdController.getRecord();
    if(mr.Id != null) {
        mr.Sample_ID__c = [SELECT Sample_ID__c FROM Match_Record__c WHERE Id = :mr.Id].Sample_ID__c;
    }
}
```

Comment: For that last option, might as well just query `WHERE Id = :controller.getId()`. That way you can one-line the whole thing. Does force you to insert the record when testing, however.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, each specific pattern has advantages and drawbacks anyways. I like the first one, except FLS can prevent the query from working, the second creates code you can't cover, and the third needs an extra query. It's kind of a "choose your own poison," since there isn't one clear winner.

Comment: Except if you one-line the if statement and move the list outside your conditional block, you can still get 100% coverage. I do tend to use 2 or 3 but  2 feels the cleanest even despite the dreaded `isRunningTest` check.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, a one-liner if statement for code coverage is just as gimmicky as being forced to include Test.isRunningTest in live code. I'd prefer salesforce just fix it so addFields runs in test mode (e.g. as a no-op), or any other equally non-gimmicky way.

Comment: Most definitely those changes would make it make it the hands-down winner for me.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks!  The top method worked.  I had tried the second earlier, but it was throwing an error saying it can't do this after setting the records, or something similar.  Haven't tried the query manually way yet, but I'll mess with it just for fun.

Comment: @user44478 Yeah, addFields is only valid before *before* you call getRecord or after you call *reset*, which discards any prior changes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `addFields` on your `StandardController` instance. Note that this call isn't supported for controllers you instantiate in the test context.

```
public MatchExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    // add this line to your constructor:
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Sample_Id__c'});
    mr = (Match_Record__c)controller.getRecord();
}
```

Also, while it's not strictly necessary, I recommend using `private set` on `mr` as well. Your page surely isn't setting it, and you don't really need a public setter to test this extension either.

```
public Match_Record__c mr { get; private set; }
```