# Get data from apex standardcontroller into extension

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller, extension

I have a custom object standardcontroller and an extension. I have embedded a VF page on the custom object's pagelayout. When the new custom object is created, I want to be able to access the custom object fields in my extension.

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" extensions="MY_Controller">
```

My constructor looks like this (not sure if this matters):

```
public ApexPages.StandardController stdCntrlr {get; set;}
public My_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    stdCntrlr = controller;
}
```

So when I create Custom_Object__c I want to be able to access all Custom_Object__c fields in MY_Controller. (not just in the VF page)
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you also go through a nice blog written by Bob, where he has explained everything about how to get extra fields of record in extension.

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2011/04/dynamic-visualforce-bindings-and.html

```
public class AddFieldsController 
 {
  public AddFieldsController(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl)
   {
      stdCtrl.addFields(new List<String>{'Name', 'BillingCity'});
       Account acc=(Account) stdCtrl.getRecord();
   }
 }
```

The above code will help developer to get Name and BillingCity also queried for him.

Hope this gives you an idea about what you are actually looking for. :)

Comment: `stdCtrl.addFields(new List<String>{'Name', 'BillingCity'});`
     ---This is important or it complains about not having included the field in the SOQL

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you complete this Trailhead module: **[Create a Controller Extension](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/salesforce_developer_workshop/steps/creating_controller_extension)**. It would also be worth reading up on [Introduction to Controllers and Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_Controllers_and_Extensions).

You can get the record from the controller using the `getRecord()` method:

```
Custom_Object__c record = (Custom_Object__c)controller.getRecord();
```

Notice how I put the type in parentheses before instantiation. That is called casting (or type-casting). Since `getRecord()` returns an `SObject` instance, we have to tell the compiler that this particular instance is actually a more specific type, namely `Custom_Object__c`.

From the `Visualforce` context, all the field which are referenced on the page get pulled in. If you want to manipulate fields which are not needed on the page, there are [multiple ways to pull in additional fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/172172/2995).

From a *unit test* context, the record will have all fields populated which you already specified. So if you create a test `Custom_Object__c` record and populate its `Name`, your controller would be able to use that even if the page doesn't reference the field.

Comment: Thanks! I will take the time and read through the documentation you provided.